# Data Insertion in Influx dB

Tags: go, influxdb

I have following payload that I am trying to persist in my influx dB.

Payload

```
{
"payload": {
  "version": "1",
  "thingModelId": "123",
  "thingModel": "a",
  "thingId": "a1",
  "tenantId": "b1",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "Speed",
      "value": 0,
      "quality": true,
      "timestamp": 5
    },
    {
      "name": "Power",
      "value": 0,
      "quality": false,
      "timestamp": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Temparature",
      "value": 27,
      "quality": true,
      "timestamp": 1688997591611
    }
  ],
  "eventType": "EVENT",
  "eventTime": 1692678618357,
  "eventId": "213",
  "assetType": "a",
  "assetId": "a1"
}
```

}

Now, I am trying to insert the same in my influx dB.

Tags
EventType, TenantId, ThingId

And rest in FieldSet.

But when we look at the Parameters array. Every Object has name, value, quality and timestamp. If I try to store it as _field and _value pair then it is getting store as

field 1
name
value 1
Speed
field 2
quality
value 2
true

and so on...

In this scenario I am unable to link that this particular quality is of which param name.

How to address that?

Basically I want to store multiple _value against a particular _field , how to achieve that using?